# Error while adding GitHub to my CV

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I was trying to link my GitHub account to my Stack Overflow CV.
In doing so I was redirected to GitHub to authorize this operation. However clicking the authorize application button had no effect.

In the browser console there was the following error:

```
Refused to send form data to 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/255386/import/github?code=b5730709c9801a629507' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' github.com gist.github.com"
```

Comment: I can't seem to repro this, is it still an issue?

Comment: @DeanWard If I look at my CV now, I can see the GitHub account. So despite of the error the action seems to have succeeded nonetheless